# Changing MySQL connection in the event of failure - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, mysqli, connection

I'm working on a project where I need to test a remote MySQL connection and if it fails, then I need the code to switch over to using a local MySQL connection.  The problem I'm running into is the code always displays the error which really kills the end-user experience.

Things I've tried:

1. try and catch exception <- got it to display a custom message, but nothing else.
2. suppressing the error with an @ <- this really really affected the loading of the page.
3. yelling at the computer <- didn't work, but I felt better.

Code:

```
//-----Remote MySQL Server-----------
$rem_host="99.99.999.999"; //Host Name 
$rem_user="testUser"; //MySQL Username 
$rem_pass="testPass"; //MySQL Password 
$rem_db="testDb"; //Database Name 


//----Local MySQL Server-----------
$local_host="127.0.0.1"; //Host Name 
$local_user="testLocal"; //MySQL Username 
$local_pass="passLocal"; //MySQL Password 
$local_db="localDb"; //Database Name 


$remoteConnection = mysqli_connect("$rem_host","$rem_user","$rem_pass","$rem_db");

if(!$remoteConnection){ $check_connection=0; }
else{ $check_connection=1; mysqli_close($remoteConnection); }


if($check_connection==1){

$db_host = $rem_host; //Host Name 
$db_user = $rem_user; //MySQL Username 
$db_pass = $rem_pass; //MySQL Password 
$db_name = $rem_db; //Database Name 

}
else{

$db_host = $local_host; //Host Name 
$db_user = $local_user; //MySQL Username 
$db_pass = $local_pass; //MySQL Password 
$db_name = $local_db; //Database Name 

}

?>
```

Comment: `if($check_connection=1){` is _assigning_ the value `1` to `$check_connection`. Use `==` for equality test.

Comment: That was a typo, but not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Change line number 2 as per your choice. First i get URL and then check it has "localhost" word then i follow localhost detail (I am using localhost/ in local machine ). If $actual_link cannot get localhost then follow online detail

```
<?php
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if (strpos($actual_link,'localhost') !== false) 
{
    //local db detail
    $servername='localhost';     
    $dbusername='root';          
    $dbpassword='';              
    $dbname='db_gbook';
    echo "local";
}
else
{
    //online db detail
    $servername='localhost';     
    $dbusername='dbaname';          
    $dbpassword='dbpassword';              
    $dbname='yourdbname';
    echo "web";
}

global $link;
$link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbusername","$dbpassword");
if(!$link)
{
    die("Could not connect to MySQL");
}
mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());    
echo "Succesive";
?>
```

Comment: That is brilliant, but my HTTP Host is always going to be local.  The pages are running on a local apache server all the time.  These pages are going to be used on a tablet that may or may not have an internet connection at various points.  If the internet connection is live, then I need to use the remote mysql server, otherwise I need to rely on the local mysql server, then synchronize the tables when a connection is restored.

Comment: when connection is live what is the url of page?

Comment: The url of the page will be localhost/page.php no matter if the tablet has an internet connection or not.  The actual local apache server resides on the tablet itself.  The pages are never going to be pulled down from an external server, only mysql data will coming from an external server.

Comment: Your connection will be successfully to online server to localhost from php?

Comment: The pages are always local, regardless if there is a internet connection or not.  The only thing that changes is where the user inputs from the pages will be stored.  Either to a local mysql database if there is no internet connection, or to a remote mysql database if there is an internet connection.  This is getting convoluted :)